# Java Iterator in for-loop NullPointerException

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list, nullpointerexception

I do not understand why a **java.lang.NullPointerException** is thrown with the following code (at this line: ***iterator = chapterKeywords[z].iterator();***):

```
Iterator<String> iterator;

        for (int z = 0; z < chapterKeywords.length; z++) {

            try {

                iterator = chapterKeywords[z].iterator();
                //exception thrown here after first iteration (i.e., when z = 1) and subsequent ones

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                    System.out.println(iterator.next());

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
               ;
            }

        }
```

Although I get the NullPointerException, the code fully executes. FYI, chapterKeywords is a LinkedList Array where each array element is a LinkedList (e.g., singleChapterKeywords).

```
LinkedList<String>[] chapterKeywords = new LinkedList[numFiles];
LinkedList<String> singleChapterKeywords = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Although the program seems to run fine, I would like to understand why the NullPointerException is thrown as I would like to completely eliminate it. Basically, the exception is thrown at the start of each iteration in the for-loop. I've modified the code to create a new iterator inside the loop, create an array of iterators, etc but they all yield the same result: **NullPointerException** at ***iterator = chapterKeywords[z].iterator();***.

Any help or insight into eliminating this exception is greatly appreciated.

So, here are my questions:

***Why is there a NullPointerException thrown at each subsequent iteration when the iterator variable is being assigned to a new iterator?***

***How can I eliminate this exception?***

Once again, TIA!

**Update:** *I thought that* the LinkedList's *were* properly populated and worked fine, but, alas, this was not the case! Thank you all for your immeasurable help!

Comment: chapterKeywords[z] is null for one or more values of z

Comment: Thanks. Most certainly, chapterKeywords[z] was all hosed up!

Comment: To make matters worse I had accidentaly included the above loop into another loop (missed it by a bracket!), resulting in the squaring of the number of iterations (numFiles^2 instead of numFiles!)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you've populated the lists but missed to add (some of) them to the array.

This will reveal your problem:

```
for (int z = 0; z < chapterKeywords.length; z++) {
   if (chapterKeywords[z] == null) {
      System.out.println("No list found at array index " + z);
      continue;
   }
   iterator = chapterKeywords[z].iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(iterator.next());
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Your code helped me understand that the problem layed with chapterKeywords[z] and not the iterator. Once again, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

chapterKeywords[z] is null.  It definitely exists or you would get an out of bounds error, but you didn't actually ever call something like chapterKeywords[z] = new String()..

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, chapterKeywords[z] was all hosed up!